# How to match values from multiple columns and replace with new values in multiple columns in bigquery sql?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have main table data that consists of medium, network and need to rename the values in 3 columns from a dictionary table by exact matching the values from this 3 columns. How do I do so in bigquery sql?

I currently have a dictionary table which contains data as so:

| medium | network | name | newMedium | newNetwork | newName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CPI | FBIg | campaignA | CPC | meta | campaignA |
| flyering | offline | flyerA | offline | flyering | flyerA |

and the main table as such:

| medium | network | name | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cpc | meta | campaignA | 2022-05-01 |
| CPI | FBIg | campaignA | 2022-03-01 |
| offline | flyering | flyerA | 2022-04-01 |
| flyering | offline | flyerB | 2022-04-02 |
| flyering | offline | flyerA | 2022-04-03 |

into

| medium | network | name | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cpc | meta | campaignA | 2022-05-01 |
| CPC | meta | campaignA | 2022-03-01 |
| offline | flyering | flyerA | 2022-04-01 |
| flyering | offline | flyerB | 2022-04-02 |
| flyering | offline | flyerA | 2022-04-03 |

So it will match medium, network, name and replace all values with newMedium,newNetwork,newName.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this query is what you're after:

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(dict.newMedium, main.medium) medium
  , COALESCE(dict.newNetwork, main.network) network
  , COALESCE(dict.newName, main.name) name
  , main.date
FROM
  main_table main
  LEFT JOIN dictionary_table dict
  ON (main.medium = dict.medium AND main.network = dict.network AND main.name = dict.name)
```

Basically, just LEFT JOIN both tables.  Doing this, non-matching fields will be `NULL`.  This way, you can use [`COALESCE`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions#coalesce) to use the `newField`, if it exists, or the `main.field` otherwise.